# Ionic with UI Router and child state - URL changes but not the view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

it's my first App that I'm writing with Ionic Framework and I came across a problem with UI router. It's quite simple survey app, I just want someone - after selecting face from survey to answer some additional questions. I need questions to be a child of survey because of resolve data. Problem is that when I want to go to questions state from it's parent survey only URL changes and nothing happens. No error, just nothing. It seems really easy, just replace what view with another but somehow I can get it working. Can you please help me, I'm struggling whole day now.

My routes:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('main', [
  'ionic',
  'ngCordova',
  'ui.router',
  // TODO: load other modules selected during generation
])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // ROUTING with ui.router
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/survey');
  $stateProvider
    // this state is placed in the <ion-nav-view> in the index.html
    .state('main', {
      url: '/main',
      template: '<ion-view view-title="main"></ion-nav-view>',
      // templateUrl: 'main/templates/<someTemplate>.html',
      // controller: 'SomeCtrl as ctrl'

    })
    .state('survey', {
      url: '/survey',
      templateUrl: 'main/templates/survey.html',
      controller: 'SurveyCtrl',
      resolve: {
        questions: function($stateParams, $http) {
          return $http.get('http://localhost:3100/api/surveys/new').then(function(response){
            return response.data;
          });
        }
      }
    })
    .state('survey.question', {
      url: '/questions',
      views: {
        'questions': {
          templateUrl: 'main/templates/questions.html',
          controller: 'QuestionsCtrl',
        }
      },
      params: {
        selectedFace: null
      }
  })

});
```

Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <!-- ionic meta tags -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <!-- custom meta tags -->
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> <!-- no auto telephone linking -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:700" rel="stylesheet">


    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"> <!-- can be saved to home screen on ios -->
    <title>Store Satisfaction</title>

    <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css main/styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main/styles/main.css">
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="storeSatisfaction">


    <!-- the current view will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <!-- will be a 404 during development -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-dynamic-locale/src/tmhDynamicLocale.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/localforage/dist/localforage.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <script src="main/main.js"></script>
    <script src="main/controllers/survey-ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="main/controllers/questions-ctrl.js"></script>
    <script src="main/constants/config-const.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>
```

survey.html

```html
<ion-view title="survey">
  <!-- do you want padding? -->
  <ion-content>
    <!-- content goes here -->
    <a ui-sref="main">test</a>
    <div class="main-image polygon">
     <div class="main-text">
       <p class="sub-header">smth</p>
       <p class="main-header">smth</p>
     </div>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item item-icon">
        <a><img src="main/assets/images/smile1.png" class="smiley-face" ng-click="proceedSurvey('very_good', 'positive')"></a>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item item-icon">
        <img src="main/assets/images/smile2.png" class="smiley-face" ng-click="proceedSurvey('good', 'positive')">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item item-icon">
        <img src="main/assets/images/smile3.png" class="smiley-face" ng-click="proceedSurvey('neutral', 'negative')">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item item-icon">
        <img src="main/assets/images/smile4.png" class="smiley-face" ng-click="proceedSurvey('bad', 'negative')">
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="item item-icon">
        <img src="main/assets/images/smile5.png" class="smiley-face" ng-click="proceedSurvey('very_bad', 'negative')">
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <div class="footer-text">
      Pomóż nam przekraczać nasze granice
    </div>
    <ui-view name="questions"></ui-view>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

SurveyCtrl.js

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('main')
.controller('SurveyCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {

  $scope.proceedSurvey = function(rate, type) {
    var params = {rate: rate, type: type};
    $state.go('survey.question', {selectedFace: params})
  }
});
```

Comment: can you include your SurveyCtrl.js code?

Comment: Sure, I've just posted it but it's quite simple, just getting data and changing state

Comment: Route to survey.questions will look for questions named view in index.html can you try putting ui-view in index.html

Comment: It wasn't working either because survey view was on top instead. I changed conception and gave questions it's own state and created service for passing data... maybe it's not most elegant approach but it works and the time was running out. Anyways, thanks for interest and help